# yii2 kartik 'fileActionSettings' not working

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

My code is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [

'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*', 'id'=>'inputFile'],
'pluginOptions' => [
'rtl'=>'true',
'fileActionSettings'=>['showZoom'=>true, 'showRemove' =>true, 
'showDrag'=>true],
previewFileType' => 'image',
'maxFileCount' => 4,
'showUpload' => false,
 ],
]);
```

but 'fileActionSettings' not working for me and The buttons are not displayed, please help me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you're missing an "'" before "pluginOptions".

Comment: thanks, but just showZoom works and other not working

Comment: check "previewFileType", same Problem.